# Laravel date input field default time value

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to display a default time value within an input field. For some reason the current time is showing up in my source code but is not displayed in my view.

My Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Publish On') !!}
  {!! Form::input('date','published_at', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('H:i'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Sourcecode:

```
<div class="form-group"> <label for="published_at">Publish On</label> 
 <input class="form-control" name="published_at" type="date" value="15:58" id="published_at"> 
</div>
```

What's wrong here? I am trying to get the current time and date.

Comment: Do you use some plugin eg. jQuery datepicker?

Comment: Change input type to 'time'.

Comment: @Marko: no plugin. I changed the input type to datetime it works now but: It only accepts whole numbers. If I type in 20:15 it saves 20:00

Comment: I am using this Mutator:public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date) {
      $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m', $date);
    }

Comment: Can you dump $date before `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m', $date);` ?

Comment: Ah, got it: My Mutator is H:m and my form is H:i, this caused the error. Anyway thanks for pointing into the right direction

Comment: I'm glad i was able to point you to the right direction.